# angularjs timepicker ng-change

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, timepicker

I am using AngularJS TimePicker (ui.bootstrap.timepicker).  I would like to fire an event when the timepicker is changed.  I looked for an ng-change attribute, but did not find one.

My purpose is that I would like to save the changes that are made to the model when the time is changed.  Right now I've used ng-model to set the model, but I cannot figure out how to notify the controller so it can perform the save (the model is serialized to localstorage).  I would like to avoid the use of a "Save" button if possible.

On a related note, I would also like to do the same thing for ui.bootstrap.datepicker.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use $scope.$watch to listen for changes to the timepicker (or datepicker) and call whatever is needed in the Controller. Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vSlDt3hKe7MPHV5lkpJz?p=preview) that is based on the bootstrap example but alerts whenever the time is changed. You should be able to apply a similar logic for datepicker as well.

Comment: Good and simple solution. The best part is, this works even if you share the same `Date` object between `datepicker` and `timepicker`. However, you will run into trouble if your initialization routine is not set up 100% correctly. Make sure to not create the timepicker (or its parents) unless the time has been set. Else, your initial time will always be overwritten with the current time. You can do that by using `ng-if`: `<timepicker ng-if="!!myTime" ng-model="myTime" ... />`

Comment: Domi, I am facing somewhat similar issue, can you help what to set as I didn't understood your solution in comments. posted question for same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29148040/angularjs-xeditable-plugin-bstime-weird-behaviour

Answer (score 0):

You can use in script

```
     <input type='text' class="form-control" ng-model="callMeTime.startHour" ng-change= "addTime()" id='datetimepicker1' placeholder="End Time" onkeydown="return false"/>


  <script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
   
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
        format  : "HH:mm",
    });

    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker().on('dp.change', function (event) {
        var user_time_picker1 = $("#datetimepicker1");
        user_time_picker1.val(this.value);
        user_time_picker1.trigger('input');
    });
    });
   </script>
```

Comment: HTML is <input type='text' class="form-control" min="callMeTime.startHour" ng-model="callMeTime.endHour" ng-change= "addTime()" id='datetimepicker2' placeholder="End Time" autocomplete="off" onkeydown="return false"/>