# Angular datepicker not firing ng-change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having a problem in datepicker with ng-change. The ng-change event is not firing when I change the value by "clicking the date" but working when I change the value by "typing the date".

Here's my code.

```
<input ng-change="date_change();" ng-model="date_to" id="recon-date" name= "date_to" type="text" class="form-control" date-time view="month" auto-close="true" min-view="month" format="MM-DD-YYYY">
```

I trace the problem by investigating the datepicker.js. I found out (if I'm correct) that the ngModelController.serViewValue() and $render() is not firing the ng-change.

I tried to add scope.$apply() but no luck. I am debugging this for hours and still no progress.

P.S. I don't want to use $scope.$watch() to solve this problem.

Thankss!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angularjs timepicker ng-change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17773412/angularjs-timepicker-ng-change)

Comment: Thanks but I dont want to use $watch event. I have so many date with ngchange and dont want to create $watch in every single one of them.

Comment: Try to use md-datepicker or angular-datepicker.js instead of datepicker.js

Comment: Gonna try that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Without **`ng-change`**, use a **`watch`**

```
$scope.date_to;

$scope.$watch("date_to", function(newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log("I've changed : ", to date);
});
```

Comment: Thanks but I dont want to use $watch event. I have so many date with ngchange and dont want to create $watch in every single one of them.

Comment: you can use watchcollection in that case

Comment: The whole point for using `on-change` is detecting changes made by the user, not changes triggered by code. A watch is going to run on any change, even while initialising the app and that's a problem with this approach.

Answer (score 2):

Use `$apply`, May this will help you.

```
var scope=angular.element($('#recon-date')).scope();    
scope.$apply();
```

Comment: Thanks. gonna try this when I get back. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use this
onchange="angular.element(this).scope().photoChange(this)"
instead of this
ng-change="photoChange(this)"